# Per-node default partition in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I'm configuring a small cluster, controlled by SLURM.

This cluster has one master node and two partitions.
Users submit their jobs from worker nodes, I've restricted their access to the master node.
Each partition in the cluster is dedicated to a team in our company.

I'd like that members of different teams submit their jobs to different partitions without bothering with additional command line switches.

That is, I'd like default partition for `srun` or `sbatch` to be different depending on the node, running these commands.

For example: all jobs, submitted from the host `worker1` should go to the `partition1`,
and all jobs, submitted from the hosts `worker[2-4]` should go to the `partition2`.

And all invocations of `sbatch` or `srun` should not contain `-p` (or `--partition`) switch.

I've tried setting `default=YES` on different lines in `slurm.conf` files on different computers, but this did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using `SLURM_PARTITION` and `SBATCH_PARTITION` environment variables, put in the `/etc/environment` file.

Details on environment variables are in manual pages for `sbatch` and `srun`